# Insert Formula into text box - Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, countif

I think I have a pretty simple problem i can't figure out, I have 4 text boxs that display information like the one below, what I want to do is enter a formula in this text box so that when my data is refreshed the values change but the formatting stays the same.

I have the countif statements all working but I can't figure out how to add the formulas to the text boxes, I'm i missing out on something here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Excel supports formulas in text boxes, you'd have to use VBA.

As a workaround, maybe you can put the formula in a cell and then format it (and the surrounding cells) to replicate the text box design?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but, yes, you can add formulas to textboxes, just select the box and write the formula you want directly into the formula bar.